# Email validation using form builder in angular 2 latest version

Tags: angular

Email **validation** using model driven form in angular 2 latest version.  please give latest version angular 2 example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comes from a Cory Rylan blog post: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management

Validation service:

```
//Original version created by Cory Rylan: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management
import { IsValidDate } from '../helpers/date.helper'


export class ValidationService {
    static getValidatorErrorMessage(validatorName: string, validatorValue?: any) {
        let config = {
            'required': 'Required',
            'invalidNumberField': 'Only numbers allowed',
            'invalidDateField': 'Not a valid date',
            'invalidCreditCard': 'Is invalid credit card number',
            'invalidEmailAddress': 'Invalid email address',
            'invalidPassword': 'Invalid password. Password must be at least 6 characters long, and contain a number.',
            'invalidPasswords': 'Invalid passwords. Passwords must match.',
            'minlength': `Minimum length ${validatorValue.requiredLength}`
        };

        // console.log(" config = " + JSON.stringify(config));
        // console.log(" validator name: " + validatorName);
        // console.log(" config = req " + JSON.stringify(config["required"]));
        // console.log(" config = nan " + JSON.stringify(config["invalidNumberField"]));
        return config[validatorName];
    }

    static numberFieldValidator(control) {
        // if (control.value.match(/^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$/)) {
        //     return null;
        // } else {
        //     return { 'invalidNumberField': true };
        // }

        return null;
    }

    static dateFieldValidator(control) {
        var e: boolean;

        if (IsValidDate(control.value)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidDateField': true };
        }
    }

    static creditCardValidator(control) {
        // Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Diners Club, Discover, JCB
        if (control.value.match(/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidCreditCard': true };
        }
    }

    static emailValidator(control) {
        // RFC 2822 compliant regex
        if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
        }
    }

    static passwordValidator(control) {
        // {6,100}           - Assert password is between 6 and 100 characters
        // (?=.*[0-9])       - Assert a string has at least one number
        if (control.value.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,100}$/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidPassword': true };
        }
    }

    static passwordCompareValidator(fg) {
        if (fg.value.password === fg.value.confirmPassword) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidPasswords': true };
        }
    }
}
```

Error component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from '../services/validation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'kg-errorMessages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ErrorMessagesComponent {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() { }

  get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Html usage:

```
  <div class="ui raised segment">
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="ui form">
          <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad">
            <div class="ui-grid-row form-group">
              <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelDiv">
                <label class="ui-widget labelCheckbox">Email Address:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-grid-col-9">
                <input type="text" size="15" pInputText class="form-control" formControlName="email" autofocus/>
                <kg-errorMessages class="uiMessage" [control]="loginForm.controls.email"></kg-errorMessages>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-grid-row form-group">
              <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelDiv">
                <label class="ui-widget labelCheckbox">Password:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-grid-col-9">
                <input type="password" size="15" pInputText class="form-control" formControlName="password" />
                <kg-errorMessages class="uiMessage" [control]="loginForm.controls.password"></kg-errorMessages>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: ../helpers/date.helper this not included

Comment: it is work fine thank you

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way to validate email for Data Driven (defined in the TS file):

```
  'email': ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")]],
```

For Template Driven (defined in the HTML file):

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="email"> Email</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="email"
             class="form-control"
             ngModel
             name="email"
             required            
             pattern=" [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
      ></div>
```

Comment: please give example of confirm password and mobile no